# Saving a date with posgresql and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to save an object, `match` using a hsh:

```
hsh = {cdate: Date.today}
Match.create!(hsh)
```

but I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""
```

The `cdate` field is of type `date` in the database (not `datetime`).
Also if I try

```
Match.create!(cdate: nil)
```

I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ".429750"
```

I have tried restarting my computer and restarting postgresql and I am still getting the same errors. What is happening?

Comment: I tried the same code on my machine (with postgresql db) and it worked fine. Can you share the schema for your Match table?

Comment: Thanks, that adds weight to my suspicion that it is some sort of corruption of the database. I am going to try loading in a back-up and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by reinstalling postgresql;

```
brew update; brew reinstall postgresql
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

As a precaution, **do not forget** to backup your database first.